# Regular Expression Fun

Tags: regex

This is what I have so far:

```
^/fe/(?:[0-9A-Za-z]{2,30}?/?+)([$|#|\?]+?)
```

with `/fe/$1`

I need to support:

- rewriting "/fe/abc123/#blah" to "/fe/#blah"
- rewriting "/fe/abc123/?ggg#blah" to "/fe/?ggg#blah"
- rewriting "/fe/abc123#blah" to "/fe/#blah"
- rewriting "/fe/abc123?ggg#blah" to "/fe/?ggg#blah"
- rewriting "/fe/abc123" to "/fe/"
- rewriting "/fe/abc123/" to "/fe/"

Currently the first 4 are captured correctly.
I still have problem with the last two.

You can play with this here:
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?35ess

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: So whats the difficulty, how close is your current regex which doesn't it match?

Comment: The part `([$|#|\?]+?)` should be `([$|#|\?]+)?`. The `?` right after `+` makes it non-greedy. What you seem to be wanting is to make the match before it optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply match one path-element (anything except for slashes, hashes and question marks), and then an optional slash:

```
Find what: ^/fe/[^/#?]+/?
Replace with: /fe/
```

[Working demo](http://regexr.com?35eu9)

Comment: Simple and does what I needed - Many thanks!!!